# Submitting POST request to Facebook Messenger API

Tags: facebook, post, https

I'm struggling to connect to the Facebook Messenger API. The server keeps returning:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I've been at this for a few days, tried multiple methods, even tried a few VS packages that don't quite work. I've checked my Auth Token several times, and I don't know what else it might be.

Is there something obvious that's causing a bad request? I've copied the root URL from Facebook's API page. The token in the code below has been removed. The application throws an exception when I attempt to read the response. (WebResponse FBresponse = FBrequest.GetResponse();)

```
private string FBSendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    string result = null;
    string FBroot = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=";
    string token = "EAA...DZD";
    string FBURI = FBroot + token;

    string FBstring = "{ \"recipient\": { \"id\":\"" + user + "\" }, \"message\": { \"text\":\"" + message + "\" } }";

    try
    {

        //using (WebClient FBclient = new WebClient())
        //{
        //    result =
        //        FBclient.UploadString(FBURI, FBstring);
        //}

        HttpWebRequest FBrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FBURI);

        FBrequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        FBrequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        FBrequest.Method = "POST";
        FBrequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        byte[] FBbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FBstring);
        FBrequest.ContentLength = FBbytes.Length;

        Stream FBstream = FBrequest.GetRequestStream();

        FBstream.Write(FBbytes, 0, FBbytes.Length);

        FBstream.Close();

        WebResponse FBresponse = FBrequest.GetResponse();

        Output((((HttpWebResponse)FBresponse).StatusDescription), Log.Error);

        FBstream = FBresponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader FBreader = new StreamReader(FBstream);

        result = FBreader.ReadToEnd();

        FBreader.Close();
        FBresponse.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Output(ex.Message, Log.Error);
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: There should be an actual API error message in the response body.

Comment: @CBroe there is. I started using Fiddler last night to monitor the traffic and it's sending me an error, but for some reason, my code isn't reading the error, it's failing before I get to read it. It fails when I try to read the response, so I suspect I'm attempting to read it incorrectly.

Comment: Sometimes the request body is discarded when the status code indicates an error. Check if the package you are using for HTTP requests offers any options in that regard.

Comment: I never did figure out how to read the discarded status code. I found a code example on how to do it, but it wasn't valid, at least with the release I'm working with. Other than the error handling, the code works as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined that my code isn't the issue. The issue is that I'm making a request with an invalid user id. Facebook creates a user ID in the application context that isn't the same as your default user id. I have to receive a message to learn that contextualized id before I can send a message.

Comment: To be precise, the id is paged-scoped. (For every page that your bot runs on, it will see a different page-scoped id for the same user.)